# Loading DLL's in Python

Tags: python, c, module, extending

I'm following the guide found here:

http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/c_extensions.html

for creating C extensions to python.  But when I try to run any python program after building that module, such as the first one listed or mandelbrot.py (listed towards the end of the page).  I get the error on the line `libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)`

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cos.py", line 5, in < module >
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libc.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Linux so I'm not sure if that is the problem.  And if it is, how would I accomplish this on Linux?  I know dll is how Windows refers to shared objects. But does the syntax change? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: When showing tracebacks like this put them in a codeblock to avoid this issue.

Comment: I should've do it considering it's pretty obvious to put tracebacks in a code block.  I must've been in a rush at work and forgotten.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GNU/Linux the cos() function is located in a library called libm.so. So you need to replace "libc.dylib" with "libm.so".

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot, where do I replace that file exactly?  Where is libc.dylib typically located?  And what's the most reliable way to get a clean copy of libm.so?

Comment: No, you shouldn't replace any files on your system. Just change the code to ctypes.CDLL("libm.so", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL) instead of ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL).